# keep div active until new function runs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to show a div inside another div , basically when i click on active (a list item) , An active order div will be displayed and stay active until i click on any other list item . I tried simple js code but the problem is ,when i click on active my hidden Div show for like mini-seconds and then disappear automatically i want the div to stay active until i click any other list item

```js
function showactive() {
  document.getElementById('active_order').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#tab_menu_order {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  color: var(--secondary);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#manage_order {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#order_list_items {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#order_list_items a {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#order_list_items a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  color: yellow;
}


/*hidden div css********************************/

#show_each_div {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid greenyellow;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hidden_boxes {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab_menu_order">
  <h1 id="manage_order">
    Manage Orders
  </h1>
  <ul id="order_list_items">
    <a href="" onclick="showactive()">Active</a>
    <a href="">Missing details</a>
    <a href="">Awaiting details</a>
    <a href="">Deliver</a>
    <a href="">Completed</a>
    <a href="">Cancelled</a>
    <a href="">All</a>
  </ul>
  <div id="show_each_div">
    <div style="display: none;" class="hidden_boxes" id="active_order">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="hidden_boxes" id="missing_details">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="hidden_boxes" id="Awaiting_review">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="hidden_boxes" id="deliver">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="hidden_boxes" id="completed">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="hidden_boxes" id="cancelled">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="hidden_boxes" id="all">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

kindly guide me what the issues i am facing , or tell me any best way to do this

Comment: you dont ened to sue JS at all in your case. you can use `:target` to show the element you clicked on with the anchor. Just add the id of the element as href in the anchor

Comment: Please use correct spellings in your answers and comments !

Answer (score 1):

No need for scripting at all. Youc an do this by using the anchor to direct to an element's id such as `<a href="#id-of-element">`.

Then hide all the boxes with: `.hidden_boxes { display: none; }`

Last but nto least you make those element visible again by using: `:target { display: flex; }`

```css
.hidden_boxes {
  display: none;
}

:target {
  display: flex;
}

/* original CSS */
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#tab_menu_order {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  color: var(--secondary);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#manage_order {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#order_list_items {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#order_list_items a {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#order_list_items a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  color: yellow;
}


/*hidden div css********************************/

#show_each_div {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid greenyellow;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hidden_boxes {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab_menu_order">
  <h1 id="manage_order">
    Manage Orders
  </h1>
  <ul id="order_list_items">
    <a href="#active_order">Active</a>
    <a href="#missing_details">Missing details</a>
    <a href="#Awaiting_review">Awaiting details</a>
    <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
    <a href="#completed">Completed</a>
    <a href="#cancelled">Cancelled</a>
    <a href="#all">All</a>
  </ul>
  <div id="show_each_div">
    <div class="hidden_boxes" id="active_order">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden_boxes" id="missing_details">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden_boxes" id="Awaiting_review">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden_boxes" id="deliver">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden_boxes" id="completed">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden_boxes" id="cancelled">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden_boxes" id="all">
      <h1>No data available</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks thats work when i add id to :target

Answer (score 0):

Because the element you are targeting for the click event is an anchor tag, you first have to prevent the default behavior(which is to navigate to the `href` of the anchor). You can do that by passing the `event` into the function and then using [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
function showactive(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('active_order').style.display = "flex";
}
```

```css
#tab_menu_order
{
    margin: 5px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: var(--secondary);
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid red;

}

#manage_order
{
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#order_list_items
{
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
   margin-top:5px ;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#order_list_items a
{
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top:5px ;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#order_list_items a:hover
{
    transition: 0.3s linear;
    color: yellow;
}

/*hidden div css********************************/
#show_each_div{
    margin-top:5px ;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid greenyellow;
    padding: 5px;
}
.hidden_boxes
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab_menu_order">
    <h1 id="manage_order">
        Manage Orders
    </h1>
    <ul id="order_list_items">
        <a href="#" onclick="showactive(event)">Active</a>
        <a href="#">Missing details</a>
        <a href="#">Awaiting details</a>
        <a href="#">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#">Completed</a>
        <a href="#">Cancelled</a>
        <a href="#">All</a>
    </ul>
    <div id="show_each_div">
        <div class="hidden_boxes" id="active_order">
            <h1>No data available</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden_boxes" id="missing_details">
            <h1>No data available</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden_boxes" id="Awaiting_review">
            <h1>No data available</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden_boxes" id="deliver">
            <h1>No data available</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden_boxes" id="completed">
            <h1>No data available</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden_boxes" id="cancelled">
            <h1>No data available</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden_boxes" id="all">
            <h1>No data available</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```